# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600" I am getting error

Tags: error

While running `./getcov -s` from Jenkin to MAC-OS and I am getting following errors:

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -600 for the file /Users/imacsbuild/Documents/XXX/XcodeCoverage-master/lcov/index.html.

Has anyone come across such errors?

Comment: LSOpenURLsWithRole() is usually a permissions error. Check you have execute perms

Comment: hmm... actually -600 is 'unknown' so might not be perms, but it's a generic 'proc not found' which I guess is similar to cannot execute

Comment: Related: [API documentation: LSOpenURLsWithRole()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9750475/55075).

Comment: I've had this happen in two scenarios - a) with finder and opening things from the terminal before (e.g. trying to open a file with it's associated application)..  For me a quick reboot always resolves it; AND b) when I am doing something with a different user to the user logged in on the UI - and in this case running the thing as the UI user solves it.